# R exits unexpectedly when trying to print a date vector with length more than 130K

Tags: datetime, r

I have tried the following code, and then R exits unexpectedly:

```
temp <- rep(as.Date("2009-01-01")+1:365, 365)
print(temp)
```

Anyone tried this before, is it a bug, or if there is anything I can do?

I have increase the memory available for R from 1024M to 2047M, but the same thing happens.

Thanks.

UPDATE #1

Here's my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.11.0 (2010-04-22) 
i386-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese_Hong Kong S.A.R..950  LC_CTYPE=Chinese_Hong Kong S.A.R..950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese_Hong Kong S.A.R..950 LC_NUMERIC=C                            
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese_Hong Kong S.A.R..950    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

And actually I am trying to do some format(foo, "%y%M"), but it also exit unexpectedly - for "unexpectedly", I mean R closes itself without any signs. Thanks again.

Comment: Works for me - (on an R-2.10 on Linux). What's your sessionInfo() output?

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean by "R exits unexpectedly"? Can you, in addition to the output from `sessionInfo()` Spacedman requested, also include any errors or messages printed when this happens?

Comment: Are you using "base R" or an IDE? I've noticed "strange" behavior in R with RJ and Rterm in Eclipse, so there's a possibility that what you're seeing is not R related per se.

Comment: I guess Roman is onto something. R-2.11.1 on Windows7 doesn't do anything strange either. +1 on the `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Works in R-2.12.0 on XP Pro SP3.

Comment: @lokheart: Seems more like a problem with your computer than with R actually. What's your computer and OS?

Comment: Have you tried switching locales to see if that makes a difference? There are occasional nasty locale bugs, especially on Windows, although I have to admit that in this case it seems like a long shot. **P.S.** R quitting unexpectedly when you haven't been messing around with C or FORTRAN code (or loaded a contributed package that does) is by definition an R bug (even if it turns out to be Microsoft's fault), so I would go ahead and post this to R-devel for comment. However, if it isn't reproducible in 2.12.0 on any system it will be disregarded ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [a known bug, fixed in 2.11.1](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14267) to me. Look at [2.11.1 changelog, section BUG FIXES, 8th item](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.11.1/NEWS.R-2.11.1).

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me (R 2.12.0, running on Fedora Core 13)

You may check the output of `getOption("max.print")` and lower it a little bit (using, for instance, `option(max.print=5000)`.

In general, however, there is no need to print out such a vector, as you will not be able to read the complete output. Functions like `str(t)` or `head(t)` are your friends!