# It seems that there is a weird Segmentation Fault when using R POSIXct class

Tags: r

It seems that there is an odd issue when trying to table or convert long POSIXct variables.  It is relatively easy to get around this, but it is still annoying.  Has anyone else experienced this?  An easy example is the following

```
z <- 1472562988  
tst <- as.POSIXct(z+(1:150000), origin = "1960-01-01")  
tst2 <- z+1:150000  
segFault <- table(tst)  
segFault2 <- as.character(tst)  
segFault3 <- as.factor(tst)  
noSegFault <- table(tst2)
```

The reason I ask, is that if I import data from a sql table and want to use by() with a date index, I cannot do it without first converting my date column to a character format in SQL. Here is the output of sessionInfo():

R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15)
Platform: sparc-sun-solaris2.10 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
[1] timeDate_2120.90 ggplot2_0.8.8    proto_0.3-8      reshape_0.8.3
[5] plyr_1.2.1

Comment: Please provide your operating system, R version, installed packages, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[moved from comments]

Solaris has a smaller user base, hence is less thoroughly tested, hence there is a slightly larger possibility than usual that you have found a new bug. Update to R 2.12.1 patched (to avoid getting Ripleyed), run with --vanilla (avoid loading any other packages), and see if the problem persists. If it does, post to r-devel and/or submit a bug report (with full system details, middle name of your maternal grandmother, etc.) ... [runs fine for me on R 2.12.1 on Ubuntu Linux]

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely using an R version prior to 2.11.1 (when the segfault issue in `format.POSIXlt` was patched).  You need to upgrade to 2.11.1 or later--preferably 2.12.1.

Your code runs fine with R-2.12.1 on WinXP.

Comment: I think it's the same case like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253437/r-exits-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-print-a-date-vector-with-length-more-than-130

Comment: @Bob: your code runs for me with R-2.12.0 on WinXP.  Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: The code works fine for me on this: R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14) 
i386-pc-mingw32